# Spring boot/CRNK Custom Query Spec URL Mapping For Single Endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, crnk

I'm currently trying to change the functionality of the `QuerySpecUrlMapper` for only one specific endpoint. In particular, we want to disable the behavior that splits a string parameter by commas. I've figured out I can do this by getting the default URL mapper and calling `setAllowCommaSeparatedValue`, but I'm not sure how to do this for the specific endpoint I want. We're using Spring, and I tried Autowiring `CrnkBoot` into my Repository object so I could get the UrlMapper that way, but this breaks the whole thing in strange ways I don't yet understand. Some exception about "Cipher not initialized"

Anyone have ideas about how to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried Autowring the `CrnkBoot` instead to a configuration class? I had a similar issue when I tried to inject it into a CRNK ResourceRepository.